# State not updated with react router dom v6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I use a state to control the render of a page

App.tsx

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ThemeProvider, StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { useRoutes, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import GlobalStyles from "components/GlobalStyles";
import theme from "theme/Index";

// Components
import { checkIfInstalled } from "utils/rpc";

// RPC Connect
import { createGrpcWebTransport } from "@connectrpc/connect-web";
import { createPromiseClient } from "@connectrpc/connect";
import { Lucle } from "gen/lucle_connect";

import routes from "./routes";

function App() {
  const [isInstalled, setIsInstalled] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const location = useLocation();
  const content = useRoutes(routes(isInstalled));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname === "/admin") {
      checkIfInstalled(client)
        .then(() => {
           console.log("true");
           setIsInstalled(true))
         }
        .catch(() => setIsInstalled(false));
    }
  }, [location.pathname]);

  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <GlobalStyles />
        {content}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
}
```

routes.tsx

```
function InstalledRoutes({ isInstalled }: { isInstalled: boolean }) {
  return isInstalled ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/install" replace />;
}

const routes = (isInstalled: boolean) => {
  console.log(isInstalled);
  return [
    {
      element: <InstalledRoutes isInstalled={isInstalled} />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "admin",
          element: <Dashboard />,
          children: [
            { index: true, element: <AdminIndex /> },
          ];
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
};

export default routes;
```

I can see the output from App.tsx from console. The output is "true", but from routes.tsx, I can see "false" output.
So state is not propagated to the `routes` function. I cannot rendered the right page because of that. How to pass state to `routes`?

Comment: You *are* passing the `installed` state to the `routes` function here `routes(isInstalled)`. We can't help further without more details though. Please [edit] to provide a complete [mcve] and any further details, code, reproduction steps you feel may be relevant.

Comment: I update my post with a minimal reproductible example

Comment: Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/state-not-updated-with-react-router-dom-v6-y72v87) demo of your code, I'm unable to reproduce any state update issues like you describe. The `isInstalled` state updates and is passed all the way down without issue. Feel free to fork that sandbox and add more of your actual code to see if you can reproduce the issue there so we can inspect it live.

Comment: You've a typo in your `routes` component code in the post though, a `";"` instead of a comma in the `children` array.

Comment: I fix my issue, the state is propaged as expected. I Navigate to my another routes too earlier.

Comment: I do ```function InstalledRoutes({ isInstalled }: { isInstalled: boolean }) {
  return isInstalled ? <Outlet /> : null;
}``` and it works !

Answer (score 0):

```
function InstalledRoutes({ isInstalled }: { isInstalled: boolean }) {
  return isInstalled ? <Outlet /> : null;
}
```

does the job !